# How to sort text strings in Python case-insensitively AND deterministically

Tags: python, sorting, text, locale, case-insensitive

I have the standard requirement to sort a list of text strings case-insensitively. However additionally **this sort needs to be deterministic** in the way that two lists containing the same elements should lead to the same sorted list.

To explain the issue, consider the following two lists:

```
l1 = ['alfred', 'Berta', 'berta', 'carl']
l2 = ['alfred', 'berta', 'carl', 'Berta']
```

Obviously both lists have the same elements:

```
>>> set(l1) == set(l2)
True
```

For sorting these lists I used in a first attempt the [builtin function `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function with the `str.casefold` as `key` argument. But this leads to two *different* result lists:

```
>>> sorted(l1, key=str.casefold)
['alfred', 'Berta', 'berta', 'carl']
>>> sorted(l2, key=str.casefold)
['alfred', 'berta', 'Berta', 'carl']
```

However I require in both cases the same output

```
['alfred', 'Berta', 'berta', 'carl']
```

How can I achieve this?

The problem with my approach is that the `key` function "eats some information" of the elements to sort. So is it possible to do this with a particular `key` function to `sorted`? This function would need to retain the full case information, but still sort an upper letter next to the equivalent lower letter....

---

**Bonus question:**

How can I make this sort completely locale-independent, so that when reading the lists from the same files on machines with different country settings the final list is always sorted exactly teh same way.

Comment: You get different results not because of case, it's about order of elements in list.

Comment: Python's sort is *stable*, so for two values with the same key (`'Berta'` and `'berta'` both casefold to `'berta'`) they'll appear in the output in the same order they were in the input. You could break ties with the original value, e.g. `key=lambda s: (s.casefold(), s)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Your key function is worth its own answer, because I think it fulfills the question's requirements to the dot. Would you mind writing up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a key function that returns a tuple with the case-folded string and then the original string. This will cause the case-folded strings to be compared first, making the sort case-insensitive. Then if the case-folded strings are identical, the original strings will be compared, ensuring that the result is deterministic.

```py
def deterministic_casefold(s):
    return s.casefold(), s

sorted(l1, key=deterministic_casefold)
sorted(l2, key=deterministic_casefold)
```

Comment: Seems similar to other answers in that the answers are not extensible to all languages. The first element of tuple would be better as a canonical case insensitive comparison, rather than only a case insensitive comparison. Second element would be better as a sort key for DUCET or the CLDR root collation.

Answer (score 3):

You could first sort them with case sensitivity, and then sort again ignoring case

```
>>> sorted(sorted(l1), key=str.casefold)
['alfred', 'Berta', 'berta', 'carl']
>>> sorted(sorted(l2), key=str.casefold)
['alfred', 'Berta', 'berta', 'carl']
```

Comment: Interestingly (and surprisingly to me) this seems to be quicker than a single sort with a compound key as I and Giacomo suggested.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was asking myself the same question. Interesting indeed!

Comment: This is a cool answer. You are certainly thinking outside the box of a single key function! :-)

Answer (score -1):

My take:

```
def prepare_stable_sort(x):
    return (x.casefold(), id(x))

list(sorted(l1, key=prepare_stable_sort))
list(sorted(l2, key=prepare_stable_sort))
```

This use normal `casefold`, but add also the hash, to distinguish the cases where `casefold` gives the same results. Note: this is stable only on same processor. To remove hash attacks, I think now hash is partially randomized.

For a full solution, I would use Unicode string comparison (so it works on all locales, but also in a sensible way, although not 100% correct for specific languages), and I would add also a reproducible hash function.

Comment: [`id(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is not a hash, it's an *identity*. Two objects that are considered `__eq__` and have the same `__hash__` will still not have the same id.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: but for a string, it is not equivalent as an hash?

Comment: Not necessarily, only for strings that get interned. That's why I suggested using *the value itself* in my comment above.

Comment: @jonrsharpe right, full string is also always comparable, and it should also be quicker. But Evans' answer is more elegant (same principle).

Comment: The ID of an object should not be relied upon to produce a stable sort order. The only guarantee as to its value is that it is "unique and constant for [an] object during its lifetime) ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)); it is not guaranteed to be greater or less than the ID of a different object. For example, you may get a different sort order if you use a different Python interpreter or a different version of Python.